# LVM partition not mounting

Tags: mount, lvm, raid, disk, cryptsetup

There was a drive failure on a disk in a RAID1 configuration. I removed the bad disk and reconfigured the RAID1 to only use the good disk. When I reboot the machine there are missing LVM partitions.

From boot log:

> Mounting other filesystems: mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/crypt-stuff, missing codepage or helper program, or other error In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try dmesg | tail or so

From this message it looks like that partition failed to mount and it may be encrypted. I am not the person who configured this machine and they are not available, unfortunately.

I need a way to mount that piece of the LVM. I get the same error when I do: `mount /dev/mapper/cryp-stuff /mnt/stuff -t ext4`

I took the error message's advice and looked in dmesg: `EXT4-fs (dm-6): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem`

Not sure where to go from here...

Edit:

```
$ cryptsetup status /dev/mapper/crypt-stuff
/dev/mapper/crypt-stuff is active.
type: PLAIN cipher: aes-cbc-essiv:sha256
keysize: 256 bits
device: /dev/mapper/vg00-stuff
offset: 0 sectors size:  725106688 sectors mode: read/write
```

Does not use luks:

```
$ cryptsetup isLuks /dev/mapper/crypt-stuff
Device /dev/mapper/crypt-stuffis not a valid LUKS device.
```

Edit:
Cryptstab appears to be setup to open the disks on boot and fstab has the right stuff to mount them but the mount command that fstab issues is producing the errors in the boot log

Comment: what does `blkid /dev/mapper/crypt-stuff` return? And `kpartx -av /dev/mapper/crypt-stuff` ?